# How can I install IOS3 to my old iPhone3G?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, ios

Time ago I've changed my old iPhone 3G to my actual iPhone.

I've thought that could be a good idea to recover this old iphone, install an old IOS system (IOS3 worked perfect for this device) and give it to my mother, since she only wants to use it as a "dumphone" and a good camera photo.

How can I remove all actual information of the iPhone3G and then install IOS3?

Disclaimer:

I'm not and advanced user. I've read in this site and in google information about Cydia, redsn0w, jailbreak... but the truth is that I've barely understood how they work.

Answer (score 1):

The erase operation is easy.

- settings app, general, reset, erase all content and settings

Breaking Apple's software update mechanism to put an older iOS on the device is going to cost time to gain expertise and even if you invested hours learning how jail breaking works, you might not be able to revert the OS. Running a jailbreak on more current OS and hardware is easier, but still something quite technical. Going that far back is less likely to succeed if reading the how-to isn't giving you a clear picture how to start to jailbreak your device in question.

I would do the easy and get her a wiped device on the OS that iTunes will support rather than needing to keep jail breaking it if the user chooses to update things.